# The criteria for zero DC resistivity from Kramers-Kronig relation?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electricity, solid-state-physics, linear-systems

While studying introductory [superconductor theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconductivity), 
[Neil Ashcroft](https://www.aps.org/publications/apsnews/202105/ashcroft.cfm) came up with a criteria for [zero DC resistivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconductivity#Zero_electrical_DC_resistance) as a following:

$$\lim_{w→0}w\cdot\rm{Im} \ \it{\sigma(w)}\neq\rm{0}$$

And this must be sufficient for proving $\rm{Re} \ \it{\sigma(w)=C \ \delta(w)} \ \rm{+...}$. Meaning infinite conductivity for a DC external field.
Since this is a relation between imaginary and real parts of $\sigma(w)$, which is a response for linear passive system, I tried to apply [Kramers-Kronig relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations):

$$\lim_{w→0}Re \ \sigma(w)=\frac{2}{\pi}\lim_{w→0}P\int^{∞}_{0}\frac{sIm \ \sigma(s)}{s^2-w^2}ds\sim\frac{2}{\pi}\lim_{w→0}P\int^{∞}_{0}\frac{A+Bs}{s^2-w^2}ds$$

But this calculation seems to be some nonzero value, nor zero, nor infinity, independent of whether A is zero or not. What am I doing wrong here?